# Excel - dynamically change the displayed digits after comma

Tags: excel, digits

I would like to know if it is possible to dinamically adjust the displayed digits after comma, for example if I have the number 1.245 in cell A1 and I write "0.01" in the cell B1, the cell A1 automatically formats to show "1.25", instead if I wrote in cell B1 "0.00001" in the cell A1 it shows "1.24500".

Please note that I'm not talking about the rounding, but the digits to show.

Is it possible to do it using a formula?
Or at least using VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim numberFormatRange As Range
    Set numberFormatRange = Range("B1")
    If Not Intersect(Target, numberFormatRange) Is Nothing Then
        If IsNumeric(numberFormatRange) Then
            Range("A1").NumberFormat = Replace$(numberFormatRange.Value, "1", "0")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```